# как разблокировать виртуальный диск Ubuntu16.vdi из состояния недоступности?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual

Нужно было запустить виртуальную машину Ubuntu и началась такая история с виртуальным диском для этой махины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(как так у меня одна виртуальная машина здесь подразумевается диск Ubuntu16 VDI формата). Подскажите как вернуть диск из состояния недоступности?

Comment: вы, видимо, удалили или пееместили один из носителей, но вероятнее это все-таки оптический диск

Answer (score 0):

ОТВЕТ: Это был оптический диск, я ошибся. НО! Оптический диск важен только ПРИ установке ОС на виртуальную машину. После установки он не нужен, только перед запуском ВМ в настройках в пункте "Носители", первым ставить ВЖД, а потом оптический диск.